# How to Map the same DNS name to multiple websites

Tags: c#, wcf

I do not know if I sound right. I have a website which is already running on the internet. I now need to add another one which is a svc service. How can I add it under the same host name ? It should be accessible from outside the LAN. I tried but it says the page is not reachable. the server is IIS.

Comment: Is original website hosted on IIS?

Comment: At least for IIS, you can only have a single site mapping to a DNS name (domain name), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis . Reverse proxy might make the setup more complicated, but the general rule is similar.

Comment: yes, the original one is hosted on IIS

Comment: so we can only have one site mapped to one DNS name ?